# set default value to strings in Golang Struct

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm developing a program using Go, I have a Struct that contains 500 fields (it's strange but it's allright, I know)... So, some of that fields are saved in the database (Postgres) as JSON, so for example that fields are defined as:

```
MyField string `sql:"type:JSON DEFAULT '{}'"`
```

My problem is, that not all the fields are filled, when I create an object of that struct the sting are zero valued to "", so then when I try to register that in the database it gives me error. 
The only thing that I need is to set as default to some of that values null or "{}" to avoid problems in the insert.
How can I do that? Is some way using tags that I can set the default value?

Comment: What if you make the fields `*string` instead of `string`? If a field is `nil` does it do what you want?

Comment: @AndySchweig if a field is nil yes, because then it will try to insert in the DB a null value and it's ok, but I cannot save "" in a json column

Comment: This smells like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'd suggest asking a question about how to redesign that struct with 500 fields, that'll cause all sorts of problems. I'm gonna guess it's a result of poor table design leading to the [Lava Flow anti-pattern](http://antipatterns.com/lavaflow.htm).

Comment: @Schwern I cannot do that, because I download that information of various external servers, and I don't really need to make a mapping of the fields. That DB design is an stablished standart

Comment: @AndySchweig it worked pretty nice. Now am wondering, which implications come across doing it in that way?

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova https://dhdersch.github.io/golang/2016/01/23/golang-when-to-use-string-pointers.html might be of help. Also take note of [this comment about using `json: "omitempty"`](https://dhdersch.github.io/golang/2016/01/23/golang-when-to-use-string-pointers.html#comment-2614169576).